# How to use complex query by using ADO.NET

Tags: c#, ado.net

```
SELECT 
    Wot.WorkOrderType,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Wo.Status =  'C' THEN 1 END) as [Completed],
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Wo.Status = 'E' THEN 1 END) as [Error]
FROM WorkOrder_2002 Wo
INNER Join  WorkOrderType Wot ON Wo.WorkOrderTypeId= wot.Id
WHERE Wo.CreateTime BETWEEN '2012-04-01' AND '2012-05-15'
GROUP BY Wo.WorkOrderTypeId,Wot.WorkOrderType
ORDER BY Wo.WorkOrderTypeId,Wot.WorkOrderType
```

I want to use above mentioned query to retrieve records by using ADO.NET(I want to pass this query in SqlCommand). 
I want to pass two dates in where clause.

Comment: You are passing two dates.  What are you really looking for?

Comment: I will get some statistics based on the start date and end date. I want to display those statistics to the user by using gridview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(CONNECTIONSTRING);
connection.Open;

SqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT 
        Wot.WorkOrderType,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN Wo.Status =  'C' THEN 1 END) as [Completed],
        COUNT(CASE WHEN Wo.Status = 'E' THEN 1 END) as [Error]
    FROM WorkOrder_2002 Wo
    INNER Join  WorkOrderType Wot ON Wo.WorkOrderTypeId= wot.Id
    WHERE Wo.CreateTime BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate
    GROUP BY Wo.WorkOrderTypeId,Wot.WorkOrderType
    ORDER BY Wo.WorkOrderTypeId,Wot.WorkOrderType";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startdate", DateTime.Parse("2012-04-01"));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@enddate", DateTime.Parse("2012-05-15"));

// Do whatever you want with the SqlCommand now...
```